# Is there a way to re-build a physical machine (into golden image) without dedicated hardware?

Tags: snapshot, desktop

I have a small office (total of 6 computers) for translation,
Due to the fact that many of the documents are private and personal and the security risk of opening word documents, pdf and so, I would like to achieve a situation in which at the end of te day the machine will "revert" into a base image (golden image).

Is there a way to do so without dedicated hardware?

Thank you!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: We are using Ubuntu, but we can use another system as well if there is a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a PXE server that allows to provide a boot image to the desktops. Set up the desktops to boot over the network via PXE. That way you have a fresh system after each boot.

Technically this still requires dedicated hardware (the server), but it doesn't require to add hardware to every desktop, which I assume is you want to avoid.

Another upside: your desktops don't need their hard disks anymore, you could mount all of them in the server and use them as shared storage.

Comment: Thank you @Gerald Schneider, that sounds like a good idea